# AWS Cloudformation nested stack deployment template path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, nested-stack

I'm trying to deploy nested stack using command

> `aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name "${STACK_NAME}" --template-file "${S3_ROOT_TEMPLATE}" --parameter-overrides ${PARAMS[@]} --region ${REGION}`

But despite the `S3_ROOT_TEMPLATE` having proper url, I get the error

> Invalid template path
> https://`<s3-bucket-name>`.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sm-domain-templates/main_stack.yaml

Any idea what's wrong with the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though in the console you have to use S3 path, in the `awscli` command, it expects the local file path of the root stack file

Answer (score 0):

The following command deploys a template named S3_ROOT_TEMPLATE to a stack named STACK_NAME:

```
STACK_NAME="cfn-demo"
S3_ROOT_TEMPLATE="cfn-demo.yaml"
REGION="us-east-1"
bucket_name="cfn-demo-bucket"
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name $STACK_NAME --template-file $S3_ROOT_TEMPLATE --parameter-overrides $PARAMS[@] --region $REGION
```

If your templates are sized greater than **51,200 bytes**, then the name of the S3 bucket where this command uploads your CloudFormation template.

```
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name $STACK_NAME --template-file $S3_ROOT_TEMPLATE --parameter-overrides $PARAMS[@] --region $REGION  --s3-bucket $bucket_name
```

**For updating the stack**, you could upload the template file to the S3 bucket by using copy and then, update the stack by using the S3 object URL as the template source.

```
aws s3 cp $S3_ROOT_TEMPLATE s3://$bucket_name
aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name $STACK_NAME --template-url https://$bucket_name.s3.$REGION.amazonaws.com/$S3_ROOT_TEMPLATE
```

Comment: Thank you Zeeshan, however with nested stack, I couldn't get the root stack file from S3 working - I had to use the local file that's pointing to S3 buckets using `TemplateUrl` like `TemplateURL: !Sub 'https://${S3BucketName}.s3.${AWS::Region}.${AWS::URLSuffix}/${S3KeyPrefix}/iam_stack.yaml'`